# ffmpeg installation: pkg-config can't find package (using Homebrew)

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew, pkg-config

I'm trying to install `ffmpeg` with Homebrew using the command

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype
```

but get

```
ERROR: freetype2 not found using pkg-config
```

If I check `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, the file `freetype2.pc` exists. In fact,

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

includes `freetype2`.

I've tried reinstalling `pkg-config` and `freetype` with Homebrew, reinstalling `git`, updating Homebrew, upgrading Homebrew, uninstalling and reinstalling all Homebrew packages, etc.

`brew doctor` gives mostly a bunch of warnings about dylibs, config scripts, and header files, probably from recently moving to a new machine and copying files. I thought the config scripts might be related, but they're all `pyenv` shims.

I'm ok with a nuclear fix, but I feel like I've tried every nuclear option I know other than creating an entirely new user account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally successful, although I'm not sure if every step that follows was required.

1. Use `brew bundle` to save a list of all brews in the file `./Brewfile`.
2. Uninstall Homebrew a la [these instructions](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew). (Also `rm` the contents of the `local` directory the uninstaller recommends.)
3. `brew bundle` to reinstall brews from `Brewfile` (must have working directory with `Brewfile`).
4. Uninstall `xquartz` via `brew cask uninstall xquartz`
5. Install `ffmpeg` with `brew install ffmpeg --with-freetype` ... no error!
6. Install `xquartz` with `brew cask install xquartz`

I think steps 4-6 might have worked without 1-3, but I'm not positive because after step 3 I had a new error from the `ffmpeg` installation:

```
libavdevice/xcbgrab.c:25:10: fatal error: 'xcb/xcb.h' file not found
```

I thought to try uninstalling `xquartz` due to [this obscure comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/20506#issuecomment-343536488) in a thread describing this second error.

Comment: Note that simply reinstalling `xquartz` did *not* work. It had to be uninstalled for the second error to go away during installation.